# Как спарсить через beautifulsoup4 в python данные с одинаковым классом?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, класс

https://www.loudsound.ru/catalog/srednechastotniki/avatar_mbr_61/ вот ссыль для парса, необходимо получить номинальую и максимальную мощность во вкладке характеристики, там несколько таблиц с одинаковым классом, помогите пожалуйста<3

Comment: сначала заходите в класс `tabs__tr_1`, оттуда берете уже значения классов `tabs__td tabs__td_1` и `tabs__td tabs__td_2`. Затем проделываете тоже самое для класса `tabs__tr_2`

Comment: Там несколько таблиц с одинаковыми классами, я не понимаю как взять именно ту, которую мне нужно с мощностью

Comment: soup.findAll('table')[1]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```python
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = r'https://www.loudsound.ru/catalog/srednechastotniki/avatar_mbr_61/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
powers = soup.find("div", string=re.compile(r"Мощность")).findNext().find_all('td')
strip = lambda x: x.contents[0].text.strip()
result = dict([(strip(powers[i]), int(strip(powers[i+1]))) for i in range(0, len(powers), 2)])
print(result)
```

###### Вывод:

```console
{'Max (Пиковая мощность), Вт': 140, 'RMS (Номинальная мощность), Вт': 70}
```